# Evaluation of $I=\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy$ by change of variable

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

I am asked to evaluate: $$I=\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy$$ where R denotes the quadrant $x, y \ge 0$, by converting to polar coordinates, ie. $$x=r\cdot \cos(t) \ ,y = r \cdot \sin(t)$$ I have worked this out to $I=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

My issue is with the following...I also tried the change of variables as:$$x=\cos(t) \ ,y = \sin(t)$$
taking t in the range of: $t \in [\pi/4, \pi/2]$. These were taken this way since for those values of t: $x, y \ge 0$.

Differentiating we get: $$dx = -\sin(t)dt  \\  dy = \cos(t)dt$$

However this does not work out to $I=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, which is the correct answer. Any reasons why? Is the range of $t$ incorrect? Or is the change of variable incorrect? If so, why?

My working:

$$\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy$$
$$=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} e^{-(\cos(t)^2+\sin(t)^2)} \,(-\sin(t)dt)\,(\cos(t)dt)$$
$$=-e^{-1}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}  \sin(t)\cos(t)dt\,dt$$
$$=-\dfrac{1}{2e}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}  \sin(2t)dt\,dt$$
$$=-\dfrac{e \pi}{16}$$

Comment: Since you are using polar coordinates,$r$ is not a constant...Also I think you made a typo with $dy$

Comment: But why should I convert to polar coordinates instead of just change of variable as in the second method? Thanks for remarking the typo

Comment: Yes, however since I am only changing variable with respect to t, should the Jacobian be used? I use the Jacobian when for example I have to do 2 change of variables...u= u(x, y) and v=v(x, y). I hope I am being clear.

Comment: to reach every point in the 1st quadrant you need $$x=\rho\cos t, y=\rho\sin t$$ with $0<\rho<\infty$ and $0<t<\pi/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpret the original double integral as volume under the surface (surface being defined by $f(x,y) = e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$, the region of integration being the whole x-y plane).

So when you change the variables using just $x = \cos{t}$ and $y = \sin{t}$, you would be integrating just over the unit circle. What you are trying to do is tantamount to reducing a surface integral to a line integral in a very weird way. (Weird in the sense that you changed the variables, brought it down to a simple curve, yet the integral is still a double integral). Thus your double integral needs to remain a double integral if you want to span the whole x-y plane. In short, it's conceptually wrong to reduce a surface integral to a line integral in the way you did it. (I'm trying not to invoke Green's theorem here, which does reduce surface integral to line integral).

Also, when you change the variables in a double integral using a function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, you must take into consideration the change in the differential surface element $dx dy$, which is caused by the transformation. The factor by which the differential surface changes is given by the determinant of the Jacobian.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$x^2+y^2=\rho^2$$

$$dx \,dy = \rho \,d\rho \,d \theta$$

thus

$$I=\iint_R e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy=\iint_{R'} \rho e^{-\rho^2} \,d\rho\,d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\theta \quad \int_0^{+\infty} \rho e^{-\rho^2} \,d\rho$$

Comment: Yes, that is my first method of solving this problem, which I managed to do successfully. My question is, why is the second method I mentioned incorrect?

Comment: @DylanZammit You can choos different interval for $\theta$ but the set up for the integral doesn't change, to better verify you could write down the integral you have obtained?

Comment: I have updated the post to show some steps of my working

Comment: @DylanZammit your change of variable is not correct, you are taking a parametrization of the domain as a circle arch, it can't work. In R x and y varing between $0$ and $+\infty$ whereas with your change they vary on an arch.

Comment: ok, so if,say,the domain is $x, y \in [0, 1]$, would my reasoning be correct?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DylanZammit It is not correct for the calculation of an integral over an area, what are you doing is to integrate the function $-\frac1e \sin t \cos t$ twice along the arch from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $.

Comment: @DylanZammit Well done, Thanks!